# Using Hive ntile results in where clause

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, quantile

I want to get summary data of the first quartile for a table in Hive. Below is a query to get the maximum number of views in each quartile:

```
SELECT NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY total_views) AS quartile, MAX(total_views)
FROM view_data
GROUP BY quartile
ORDER BY quartile;
```

And this query is to get the names of all the people that are in the first quartile:

```
SELECT name, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY total_views) AS quartile
FROM view_data
WHERE quartile = 1
```

I get this error for both queries:

```
Invalid table alias or column reference 'quartile'
```

How can I reference the `ntile` results in the `where` clause or `group by` clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put a windowing function in a where clause because it would create ambiguity if there are compound predicates.  So use a subquery.

```
select quartile, max(total_views) from
(SELECT total_views, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY total_views) AS quartile,
FROM view_data) t
GROUP BY quartile
ORDER BY quartile
;
```

and

```
select * from 
(SELECT name, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY total_views) AS quartile
FROM view_data) t
WHERE quartile = 1
;
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by ambiguity caused by compound predicates, could you give an example please?

Comment: SELECT col1
FROM T1
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) <= 3
AND col1 > '100'

What would the order of operation be here?  Should the col1 > '100' part of the predicate be run first or should the row numbering.

Answer (score -1):

The WHERE statement in SQL can only select on an existing column in a table schema. In order to perform that functionality on a calculated column, use **HAVING** instead of WHERE.

```
SELECT name, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY total_views) AS quartile
FROM view_data
HAVING quartile = 1
```

Comment: This answer also results in an error. Please see the accepted answer.